# How get object after filter array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to make a sum by taking data from an array after I filter I want to take a nominal object to calculate it how do I do it

my code :

```
$('#ptk-2').change(function()
let array =[
  {'val': 'k00', 'nominal': 0},
  {'val': 'k0', 'nominal': 58500000},
  {'val': 'k1', 'nominal': 63000000},
  {'val': 'k2', 'nominal': 67500000},
  {'val': 'k3', 'nominal': 72000000},
  {'val': 'tk0', 'nominal': 54000000},
  {'val': 'tk3', 'nominal': 67500000},
  {'val': 'tk2', 'nominal': 63000000},
  {'val': 'tk1', 'nominal': 58500000},
]
sum = 0
ptk_1 = array.filter(function(obj) {
  api = obj.val == $('#ptk-1').val()
  return api
})
ptk_2 = array.filter(function(obj) {
  api = obj.val == $('#ptk-2').val()
  return api
})
console.log(ptk_1.nominal);
```

Comment: Do you mean `ptk_1.reduce((sum, obj) => { sum += obj.nominal; return sum; })`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the array.forEach to iterate and get the sum:

```
ptk_1.forEach((p) => {sum += p.nominal})
```